# How to fix error 0x8007025D when installing Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I've looked at both [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1139272/error-code-0x8007025d-when-installing-windows-10-on-virtual-box) and [this other](https://superuser.com/questions/1605521/error-0x8007025d-while-making-usb-windows-10-install) question regarding this error. Both answers suggested that the installation medium has been corrupted.

I've tried several different USB drives, as well as different machines to create them. The error remains consistent.

What can I do to install Windows 10?

Comment: RAM is the installation storage medium for Windows: Windows is installed from a [WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro?view=windows-11) image that is loaded into RAM as a RAM disk mounted at `X:`. _(The error code is covered within [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolution-procedures#other-error-codes) Microsoft Docs page, but it doesn't nuance that Windows is installed from a RAM disk, so a RAM test should be done if re-creating the boot media doesn't solve the issue; I'll submit a pull request on GitHub)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The epiphany came when I ran MemTest86, which came included in my UEFI. As it turns out, one of my two RAM sticks had bad blocks. Once I removed the offending RAM, the installation continued without issue.

Comment: RAM is the installation storage medium for Windows: Windows is installed from a [WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro?view=windows-11) image that is loaded into RAM as a RAM disk mounted at `X:`